# How duality works with polynomials?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces, coordinate-systems, dual-spaces

Let $E = R_2[X]$.
Let $a \in \mathbb{R}$.
Let $ev_a : E \rightarrow\mathbb{R}, P \mapsto P(a)$.
Let $P = a + bX + cX^2$.

Show that $B = (ev_1, ev_2, ev_3)$ is a base of $E^*$.

---

**Proof** :

We have:

- $ev_1(P) = P(1) = a + b + c$
- $ev_2(P) = P(2) = a + 2b + 4c$
- $ev_3(P) = P(3) = a + 3b + 9c$

So let $A = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 2 & 4\\
1 & 3 & 9
\end{pmatrix}$.

It is a Vondermonde matrix, its det is not zero, so $B$ is a base of $E^*$.

---

I know that the result is okay but I cannot understand why it works and links it with de definitions, especially with polynomials and coordinates (I understand how duality works in $\mathbb{R}^n$). Here are some random knowledges that I cannot put together:

Let $C$ = $(1, X, X²) = (c_1, c_2, c_3)$.
We have $c_i^*(c_j)=\delta_{i,j}$ so $c_1^*(P)=c_1^*(a+bX+cX^2)=a$.
What can be the dual base of $C$?
$(ev_1, ev_2, ev_3)$ is a base of $E^* \iff \forall \phi \in E^*, \exists! \alpha, \beta, \gamma \in \mathbb{R} : \phi = \alpha ev_1 + \beta ev_2 + \gamma ev_3$.
How the **Proof** I gave is correct?

Comment: I’m not sure I get your question right. What is it that you try to prove ? Of course the dual base of your C is just $(c_1*,c_2*,c_3*)$.

Comment: And your proof make no sense as P is a polynomial and the $ev_i$ are elements of $E^*$

Comment: What is the definition of a base of $E^*$ according to you ?

Comment: Hm, I edited the post, I would like to know a good proof that uses definitions to show how (ev_1, ev_2, ev_3) is a base of E^*, the joint use of spaces, functions and polynomials breaks my head @MaximeCAILLEUX

Comment: Okay ;) so what is a base of $E^*$ ? It is a family of elements of $E^*$ such that every element of $E^*$ writes as a unique combination of the elements of the family.

Comment: But you also know that in finite dimension, if your family of elements is free and of the good size (here 3 as were in dimension 3) then it is a base.

Comment: Okay, like the equivalence I put at the bottom so? How can I make the link of this equiv and the proof?

Comment: So I think I have to show phi(a+bX+cX²)=a'ev_1+b'ev_2+c'ev_3 @MaximeCAILLEUX

Comment: Now, suppose that it exists $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3\in\mathbb R$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^3 \lambda_i ev_i = \tilde{0}$ where $\tilde{0}$ is the null function of $E^*$. Then by evaluating this equality of functions (defined of E) on the elements $P_1=(X-1)(X-2)$, $P_2=(X-1)(X-3)$ and $P_3=(X-3)(X-2)$ you get that the $\lambda_i$ are zero. Hence the family of three vectors $(ev_1,ev_2,ev_3)$ is free and so a base by dimension arguments.

Comment: What you wrote you need to prove is incorrect. If you want to stick to showing that every element phi of $E^*$ can be written in terms of the $ev_i$, no coefficients of polynomial should be involved. I edit this message since I had no seen the primes on your coefficients. But you should not think about the coefficients of the polynomials you work with as it could mislead you.

Comment: In maths language, this is what you should prove : $\forall\phi\in E^*,\exists!(t_1,t_2,t_3)\in\mathbb{R}^3,\;\text{such that}\;\phi=t_1 ev_1+t_2 ev_2 + t_3 ev_3$

Comment: Okay thank you, I think I am NEAR to get it, how did you found $P_1$, $P_2$, $P_3$?

Comment: I chose these polynomials because each time two out of the three ev were null when evaluated on them. If you want to “create them” just think that if a polynomial is null in 1 (or 2 or 3) it means that it can factor by (X-1) (or (X-2) or (X-3)) so I chose polynomials null in 1 and 2 for example that were the easiest possible, so (X-1)(X-2) (and so on for the others).

Comment: Oh great it sounds like Lagrange's ones! @MaximeCAILLEUX

Comment: Indeed that is the spirit ;)

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your second question

> What can be the dual base of $C$?

You used the correct definition of dual basis

> We have $c_i^*(c_j)=\delta_{i,j}$

Hence the dual basis for $C$ would be $(c_1^*,c_2^*,c_3^*)$ where $\forall i=1,2,3$, $c_i^*$ of a polynomial gives the coefficient of the degree $i$ term.

Regarding your third question

> $(ev_1, ev_2, ev_3)$ is a base of $E^* \iff \forall P \in E, \exists! \alpha, \beta, \gamma \in \mathbb{R} : P = \alpha ev_1 + \beta ev_2 + \gamma ev_3$.

I suspect you have some sort of typo, since you are expressing a polynomial $P\in E$ as a linear combination of elements in $E^*$, but $E\neq E^*$.

Comment: It wasn't a typo but misunderstanding, thank you I edited the post.